# Is there an operating system API wrapper library for c++?

Tags: c++, cross-platform, operating-system

Does sombebody know a C++ library for accessing different operating system APIs?

I'm thinking about a wrapper to access OS specific functions. Something like:

> osAPI.MessageBox(); // calls MessageBox() in Win32, equivalent in Mac
>   OS Linux etc...

Since I think it's hard to realize this for different OSes for now it would be also ok to have a nice C++ wrapper class for WinAPI.

Comment: The functions you describe are not the OS layer (which handles the Device drivers etc). These are the windowing (or display) Layer, which is a layer above the Core OS.

Comment: I only chose MessageBox because it came in my mind first. In general, I don't think (only)about GUI functions, I think about typical OS API functions like process management, network stuff etc. (non-GUI-stuff in first line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost offers libraries for networking (Boost.Asio), threads (Boost.Thread), time, dates, file system traversal, shared memory, memory mapped files, etc.

ACE also has abstractions for networking, threads, time, file system stuff, shared memory, etc.

AFAIK, neither has GUI abstractions or DB abstractions either.

Others have mentioned Qt, wxWidgets and so forth.

Answer (score 7):

I think you're looking for [Trolltech's Qt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_toolkit) C++ framework.

It's a cross platform C++ library for GUI and just about everything else cross platform.

And as of the latest version it is free to use for commercial use.

Comment: Does QT also handle non-GUI OS API stuff like getting a list of running processes, for example?

Comment: Apparently getting the process list is not covered by QT. ( http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2006-10/msg01222.html )
Maybe they've added a solution in a newer release? I can't find a way to get it in wxWidgets either.

Comment: You could always fall back on #ifdef _WIN32 when needed

Answer (score 3):

[wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) comes highly recommended by a few friends who've used it.

Answer (score 1):

MFC sort of does this on Windows but is not the easiest to use.  For a cross platform C++ library take a look at [QT.](http://www.troll.no)  It's best known as a GUI toolkit, but it contains portable APIs to support many system services such as threading, database connectivity and I/O.

Answer (score 1):

Check Daynix DUSIX. It is a module that abstracts common system calls, providing a single interface for Linux and Windows user space applications and kernel modules.

See [here](http://www.daynix.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=62&Itemid=71) and [here](https://github.com/daynix/bricklets/wiki/DUSIX-bricklet-documentation).

Answer (score 0):

Yet another cross-platform C++ library is Mozilla's [XPCOM](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/xpcom/). It's the cross-platform library used by Firefox and a number of other projects.

Answer (score 0):

Nokia's QT would be your best bet if you need a wide range of cross platform functionality. The downside though is that you need to learn its Signal/Slot mechanism, you need to use it's own qmake tool, and it is not too friendly with the STL(you need to learn to use all of QT's containers).

If you are looking for something simpler for GUI development, then wxWidgets would be a much better choice.

Comment: it works fine with STL. all of the Qt containers have STL style iterators available. In addition, every Qt container has to/from methods for converting to/from STL containers.